# Keras Import Error when loading a pre trained model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning

I am trying to use a pre-trained model in Tensorflow. I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

from keras.applications import mobilenet_v2
```

I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

However, the following codes do work:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import mobilenet_v2
```

OR

```
from keras_applications import mobilenet_v2
```

The 2 methods mentioned above work but the 1st one doesn't. Why does this happen?

Comment: It may be because of space between keras and applications mentioned for ```from keras. applications import mobilenet_v2```

Comment: Actually, I accidentally added that space while asking the question. There's no space actually!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by downgrading tensorflow to version 2.0 using this command:

> pip install tensorflow==2.0

I hope it helps you.